# How can I reference a NuGet package version in a .csproj property?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, csproj

I am using a NuGet package, "PackageName", in my .NET project and I want to reference its version number in a property in my .csproj file. I need to use this version number in other parts of the .csproj file.

I tried a few things like the following code, but it didn't work:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyPackageVersionProperty>$([System.String]::Copy('$(PackageReference.PackageName.Version)'))</MyPackageVersionProperty>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The project failed to load with this code.

How can I reference the version of the "PackageName" package in a property in my .csproj file, so that I can use it elsewhere in the file?

I am not attempting do this programmatically. I want this done from inside csproj only.

Here's an example of how my csproj is right now and an example of how I would use it.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Sample.Package" Version="1.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- I have to update version below every time. I update the package. I want to have it update automatically. -->
    <NuGetPackagePath>$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(NuGetPackageRoot), "Sample.Package", "1.2.3"))</NuGetPackagePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(NuGetPackagePath)\lib\net461\xmlFromPackage.xml" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a property/variable with the version number, which you reference in both the definition of the `NuGetPackagePath` property, as also in the `PackageReference`.

Below example does so by using a `versionNumber` property.

When you need to do a NuGet package version update, you only have to change the `versionNumber`; all other parts referencing this `versionNumber` will be in sync automatically.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <versionNumber>1.2.3</versionNumber>
  <NuGetPackagePath>$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(NuGetPackageRoot), "Sample.Package", $(versionNumber)))</NuGetPackagePath>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Sample.Package" Version="$(versionNumber)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<PackageReference Include=<Name.Of.The.Package> Version=<Version of the package> />
```

An example would be:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the input... I don't think this addresses my question though. I want to be able to reference the version of a PackageReference, not create a PackageReference.

Comment: @GabrielKunkel I am also looking for something similar. Did you happen to find some solution?